# Can the same tome be used more than once?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

I have a level 17 sorceress with a Scroll of Wish, and a Tome of Leadership and Influence. I also have the wish spell.

I was wondering if I could use my scroll to go back in time 5000 years (or however many), read my tome, use the wish spell to cast sequester on myself to reawaken in a century, and read the tome again. Repeat till back to present day.

As far as I can find, there is no limit to how many times you can read tomes of the same type, and i have found nothing on reading the same one multiple times because everyone assumes you dont live long enough to read it again.

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, not discussion. Please take any discussion to [Role-playing Games Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=rpg.stackexchange.com). (Prior discussion has been removed.)

Comment: It's not QUITE a duplicate of the others. For one, the whole point is that by traveling to the past, the caster ends up "finishing" their buffing with the tomes in the character's original present. So some if the issues noted (cultural and linguistic distance from the society they end up in) don't actually occur.